# JSF HttpSession Login Passing Parameter?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have login form using Hibernate + JSF 2.0, my code working fine but my problem is how can I show user profile after login such as first name, last name, etc...My friend tell me should I use HttpSession but I can't how to use it. Hope anyone suggest me the best way. Here is my code:

**login.xhtml**

```xml
<h:form id="formLogin">
    <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:" />
    <p:inputText value="#{loginBean.username.username}"
                 id="username" required="true" label="username" styleClass="span12" />

    <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
    <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.username.password}"
                   id="password" required="true" label="password" styleClass="span12" />
    <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" update=":growl" ajax="false"
                     action="#{loginBean.login}"/>
</h:form>
```

**loginBean.java**

```
public class loginBean {

    private Users username;
    private UsersDao userdao;

    /** Creates a new instance of loginBean */
    public loginBean() {
        userdao = new UsersDao();
        username = new Users();
    }

    public Users getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(Users username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String login(){
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        FacesMessage msg;
        boolean loggedIn;

        username = userdao.login(username);
        if(username != null) {
            loggedIn = true;
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("username", username.getPassword());
            return "index";
        } else {
            loggedIn = false;
            msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Login Error", "Invalid credentials");
            if(this.username == null){
                this.username = new Users();
            }
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String logout(){
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        FacesContext facescontext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        HttpSession sesion = (HttpSession) facescontext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        sesion.invalidate();

        return "logout";
    }

}
```

Comment: Which scope is your `loginBean`?

Comment: I would recommend retrieving the user informations in the DAO with a DTO.

Comment: I don't know what is it? Could you give me example.

Comment: Why is the class whose instance represents a single user named `Users` with a plural? Why did you call the property representing a whole user instance `username`? Use `private User user;` and `#{loginBean.user.username}` or perhaps better `#{loginBean.user.name}`. Code should be self-documenting.

Comment: In addition to what @BalusC says, java class names should begin with an uppercase letter. `LoginBean` instead of `loginBean` would be better.

Comment: @BalusC How can I get session data if I use HttpSession?

Comment: A `@SessionScoped` bean is already stored in `HttpSession`. No need to manually fiddle around it. JSF has already taken care of this mess for you. Just reference `#{loginBean.username}` anywhere else in your webapp to get/print the logged-in user, as answered by Xtreme Biker.

Comment: @BalusC I did as you mentioned but in index.xhtml (afer logged-in), I reference #{loginBean.username} it said "com.entities.Users@41ebfb"

Comment: Why is that wrong? If you want to print the username of the logged-in user, just use `#{loginBean.username.username}` (and we're coming back at the fact that your code is absolutely not self-documenting; fix your bad and confusing class/variable names)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've two choices:

1. Keep `LoginBean` [`@SessionScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/SessionScoped.html) and inject it where you need it.
   Remember you can inject JSF managed beans in other ones by using
   [`@ManagedProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html) annotation. Having stored the logged user info
   into your `LoginBean` you can retrieve it from here. Also you could refer it from any of your views that way:

   `#{loginBean.userName}`
2. Change your `LoginBean` to [`@ViewScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ViewScoped.html) and let it manage only the login-related view. Then inject a `@SessionScoped` bean to this which will be called `LoginInfo`. When the login performs, create your `LoginInfo` bean, which will be accessible from the rest of the beans within the same session.

There's no need to use [`HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html). JSF provides `@SessionScoped` managed beans to avoid having to inject values there yourself.

**See also:**

- [Injecting managed beans in each other](http://balusc.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#InjectingManagedBeansInEachOther)

Comment: Thanks @xtreme-biker, I keep using method 1 but after logged in, how can I show user in new page based on userid.

Comment: i think setting a login info into a JSF managed bean is not a good practice. `HttpSession` is better to use.

Comment: @erencan setting the password shouln't be. No problem to set the rest of the info. Session managed bean uses `HttpSession` basically, so it's the same result achieved in an easier and JSF oriented way.

Comment: @thehung1724 when you log in, store what you want in the `LoginBean`. After that, inject that bean where you want using the `@ManagedProperty` annotation and get the info.

Comment: @XtremeBiker That mean I must create new viewscope to inject sessionscope?

Comment: @XtremeBiker i think injection unnecessary increases coupling between beans, which is not good.

Comment: @thehung1724 a correct JSF architecture specifies you should have each page inside your application tied to a view or request scoped bean. That beans will take care about what you are currently doing with your view. If you want to access session scoped data from that beans, just use `@ManagedProperty`. If you want to access it from the page, just reference the `@SessionScoped` bean itself.

Comment: @erencan that's JSF way to do things. JSF provides an intermediate layer to avoid having to access `HttpSession` or `HttpRequest` by yourself. If you prefer to use raw session itself, you can. However you still have to reference what you want to achieve by name, isn't it also coupling?

Comment: @XtremeBiker thanks you, i'm very new JSF, could you modify my code to help me understand clearly. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @thehung1724 the provided link explains properly how to use JSF beans and access them from other beans or from your pages. You still have much more info here in SO and through the internet. Good luck :-)

Comment: @XtremeBiker Congratulations on reaching 3000 rep (+1)!